# Can I execute commands written in a textdocument in the terminal

Tags: linux, shell, kde-plasma, fedora-25

This may be a very simple question, but after switching from windows to linux (and being forced to use the shell way... way more often than I was forced with windows), there is still much new stuff to learn for me.

I am using fedora 25 on my laptop as my "surf and work" system. So I wanted to install Spotify, to be able to listen to music.

To install the software, I have to execute 4 commands:

**1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages**

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886

**2. Add the Spotify repository**

echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

**3. Update list of available packages**

sudo apt-get update

**4. Install Spotify**

sudo apt-get install spotify-client

My Question: Can I write these commands into a textdocument and execute them as a script?

I tried it with chmod, but I just don´t get it working right.
[I used this link as help (yes, I am from germany ^^)](http://rowa.giso.de/german/shell-scripte.html)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file whose first line is:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Then put the commands after that.

Add execute permission to the file:

```
chmod +x filename
```

Then run the script as:

```
./filename
```